# Is there a way to plot multiple graphs with multiple lines on each one using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I'm trying to plot learning curves for different metrics such as training and validation loss and accuracy.

```
for lr in learning_rates: 
    opt = SGD(learning_rate = lr)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    network = model.fit(x_train_subset, y_train_subset, epochs=iterations, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)

    train_loss_values = network.history['loss']
    train_accuracy_values = network.history['accuracy']
    val_loss_values = network.history['val_loss']
    val_accuracy_values = network.history['val_accuracy']

    plt.plot(epochs, train_accuracy_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    
plt.title('Training Accuracy over Epochs for Different Learning Rates')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Training Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This is the code I have and it works exactly how I want it to for the one graph with training accuracy as the metric.

Output of the above code:

[image]

However, I want to replicate this four times for all the different metrics stored in the following code:

```
train_loss_values = network.history['loss']
train_accuracy_values = network.history['accuracy']
val_loss_values = network.history['val_loss']
val_accuracy_values = network.history['val_accuracy']
```

If I simply do the following, it does not create 4 separate graphs, it just adds all data to one.

```
for lr in learning_rates: 
    opt = SGD(learning_rate = lr)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    network = model.fit(x_train_subset, y_train_subset, epochs=iterations, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)

    train_loss_values = network.history['loss']
    train_accuracy_values = network.history['accuracy']
    val_loss_values = network.history['val_loss']
    val_accuracy_values = network.history['val_accuracy']

    plt.plot(epochs, train_accuracy_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    plt.plot(epochs, train_loss_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    plt.plot(epochs, val_accuracy_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    plt.plot(epochs, val_loss_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    
plt.title('Training Accuracy over Epochs for Different Learning Rates')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Training Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I asked ChatGPT and it always suggested running the entire neural network again 4 times, but I have already run it once and collected all the data I need in lists. I just need to create 4 separate plots.

Comment: Are you saying you want a new figure created in each of the `learning_rate` loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`plt.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) in order to display multiple plots.
`plt.subplot(2,2,i)` creates 4 plots in a 2 x 2 grid. `i` is the index of the plot you are currently setting.

```
#Set the size of your plot
plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))

for lr in learning_rates: 
    opt = SGD(learning_rate = lr)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    network = model.fit(x_train_subset, y_train_subset, epochs=iterations, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)

    train_loss_values = network.history['loss']
    train_accuracy_values = network.history['accuracy']
    val_loss_values = network.history['val_loss']
    val_accuracy_values = network.history['val_accuracy']

    plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    plt.plot(epochs, train_accuracy_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    plt.subplot(2,2,2)
    plt.plot(epochs, train_loss_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    plt.subplot(2,2,3)
    plt.plot(epochs, val_accuracy_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    plt.subplot(2,2,4)
    plt.plot(epochs, val_loss_values, label=f'LR = {lr}')
    
# Formatting for each subplot
ylabel = ['Training Accuracy', 'Training Loss', 'Validation Accuracy', 'Validation Loss']
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
    plt.title(f'{ylabel[i]} over Epochs for Different Learning Rates')
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel(ylabel[i])
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

I do not have your data, but the output should look like this:
[image]